# Нужно ли ставить тире во фразе?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить тире во фразе:

> Здоровье детям через спорт.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 3):

Здоровье детям ― через спорт.

Это лозунг, который имеет структуру эллиптического двусоставного предложения, в данном случае  его схема выглядит так: подлежащее ― обстоятельство.

Пауза делит предложение на две части и обозначается тире на письме.

Comment: Может кто-то прояснит отметину на ответе: «низкокачественный» из-за длины и содержимого?